# Loading Latitude longitude data using Google maps API using CSV data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, csv, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load Map data using a CSV file using Google's Map API. I tried following this example: https://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/

I was trying to load it which shows some information on clicking the markers.

My CSV data looks something like this

```
 LGA_NAME     Lat              Long        Information
DANDENONG   -37.98862   145.21805   something crashed
DANDENONG   -37.98862   145.21805   something crashed
DANDENONG   -37.98862   145.21805   something crashed
DANDENONG   -37.98862   145.21805   something crashed
DANDENONG   -37.98862   145.21805   something crashed
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/ye96s94c/2/

I cant seem to load any of the data. It shows up a blank. Not sure what could be the problem. If someone could correct it, I would be thankful.

```
function initialize() {
  var map;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  };

  // Display a map on the page
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  map.setTilt(45);

  // Multiple Markers
  var markers = [];

  // Info Window Content
  var infoWindowContent = [];

  $.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97162408/crashdata.csv', function(data) {
    var data = csvToArray(data);
    data.forEach(function(item) {
      {
        markers.push([item.LGA_NAME, parseFloat(item.Lat), parseFloat(item.Long)]);

        infoWindowContent.push([item.Information]);
      }
    });

  });
  console.log(infoWindowContent);


  function csvToArray(csvString) {

    // The array we're going to build
    var csvArray = [];
    // Break it into rows to start
    var csvRows = csvString.split(/\n/);

    // Take off the first line to get the headers, then split that into an array
    var csvHeaders = csvRows.shift().split(',');

    // Loop through remaining rows
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < csvRows.length; ++rowIndex) {
      var rowArray = csvRows[rowIndex].split(',');

      // Create a new row object to store our data.
      var rowObject = csvArray[rowIndex] = {};

      // Then iterate through the remaining properties and use the headers as keys
      for (var propIndex = 0; propIndex < rowArray.length; ++propIndex) {
        // Grab the value from the row array we're looping through...
        var propValue = rowArray[propIndex];
        // ...also grab the relevant header (the RegExp in both of these removes quotes)
        var propLabel = csvHeaders[propIndex];

        rowObject[propLabel] = propValue;
      }
    }
    return csvArray;
  }


  // Display multiple markers on a map
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    marker, i;

  // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }

  // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
  var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
  });

}
```

Comment: What about reading some *getting started* documentation about how to display a simple map? Like for example setting a **height** to your map DOM element... or give your map object the **required** options?

Comment: It was not the height. Fixed it myself: https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/aLk0c2fa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.get was out of scope for the needed objects. Silly mistake but a fix is easy.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/aLk0c2fa/

```
   $.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97162408/crashdata.csv', function(data) {
     function initialize() {
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       var mapOptions = {
         mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

       };

       // Display a map on the page
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
       map.setTilt(45);

       // Multiple Markers
       var markers = [];

       // Info Window Content
       var infoWindowContent = [];

       data = csvToArray(data);
       data.forEach(function(item) {
         markers.push([item.LGA_NAME, parseFloat(item.Lat), parseFloat(item.Long)]);
         infoWindowContent.push([item.Information]);
       });

       // Display multiple markers on a map
       var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
         marker, i;

       // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
       for (i = 0; i < markers.length - 1; i++) {
         console.log(markers[i][1]);
         var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);

         bounds.extend(position);
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: position,
           map: map,
           title: markers[i][0]
         });

         // Allow each marker to have an info window    
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
           return function() {
             infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
             infoWindow.open(map, marker);
           }
         })(marker, i));

         // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
         map.fitBounds(bounds);
       }

       // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
       var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
         this.setZoom(8);
         google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
       });

     }
     initialize();
   });

   function csvToArray(csvString) {

     // The array we're going to build
     var csvArray = [];
     // Break it into rows to start
     var csvRows = csvString.split(/\n/);

     // Take off the first line to get the headers, then split that into an array
     var csvHeaders = csvRows.shift().split(',');

     // Loop through remaining rows
     for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < csvRows.length; ++rowIndex) {
       var rowArray = csvRows[rowIndex].split(',');

       // Create a new row object to store our data.
       var rowObject = csvArray[rowIndex] = {};

       // Then iterate through the remaining properties and use the headers as keys
       for (var propIndex = 0; propIndex < rowArray.length; ++propIndex) {
         // Grab the value from the row array we're looping through...
         var propValue = rowArray[propIndex];
         // ...also grab the relevant header (the RegExp in both of these removes quotes)
         var propLabel = csvHeaders[propIndex];

         rowObject[propLabel.trim()] = propValue;
       }
     }
     return csvArray;
   }
```